# Vault token lookup - Python

Tags: python-3.x, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to renew token and trying to output token info. How can i get token_lookup details using hvac.

checked with the following without any luck.

```
VAULT_URL = "https://vault.com"
VAULT_TOKEN = ".sasassasas"

client = hvac.Client(url=VAULT_URL, verify=False, token=VAULT_TOKEN)


auth = client.is_authenticated()
print(auth)
response = client.read(path="secret/apps/USERNAME/v1")
print(response)
renew_state = client.renew_token()
print(renew_state)
lookup = client.lookup_token(token=VAULT_TOKEN)
print(lookup). ## this one failed with
```

hvac.exceptions.Forbidden: 1 error occurred:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a permissions issue that may be due to the associated policy with the token. It may also be due to the underlying API where you are invoking against an endpoint for renewing a different token instead of the same token, and also using the old bindings. If you update the code for both:

```
client.auth.token.renew_self()
```

then that will fix two issues and may also fix root cause. Otherwise, you will need to fix the authorization policy (currently not shared in question). Documentation for corrected method can be found [here](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/source/hvac_api_auth_methods.html#hvac.api.auth_methods.Token.renew_self).

Comment: if token about to expire in 6h, when do we need to call the renew token method, after 3h ? or how that works ? what will happen if the renew token method call every 1 hr ? i'm bit confused when to run that method.

Comment: @Markus You set the `token_ttl` when you created the token, so it would depend on what you defined for the token.